# Former Company is suing current client

Tags: professionalism

My Former company is suing their former client, which is my current client now with new company.
Now my former company request to provide information about the previous project (3 years ago) and involve in the arbitration.

The question :

Should I involved or provide any information or not?

because from my point of view there's no benefit at all, every single penny that i spend will go into my former company and not me. 
second i may jeopardizing my career.
They called just now to be a witness and i may need to sign something.

I have a very good rapport with the client that's why the former and the current company hired me to deal with that client.

Comment: I would keep well out of it declaring that you have a mixed interest. Not sure you would be that reliable in court?

Comment: The country matters. If you are subpoenaed in the US, even in a civil case, you have to testify or risk getting cited with contempt of court.

Comment: Why the down vote? I find this to be an interesting question

Comment: Seems to me there's the half of this question that's legal - yes, if there's a legal requirement (subpoena etc) then you need to do it or get a lawyer - but then half of the question is if it's not that and just a 'request,' should you do it or not? (Hint: no).

Comment: I'm surprised no one has mentioned it, but - at least in the US - the proper thing to do would be check with your current employer's legal department before doing ANYTHING else.

Answer (score 6):

You don't work for the former company anymore, so it's none of your business anymore.

In your current situation it is more important for you to maintain the relationship to your current client than your previous employer. When your former employer asks for your involvement, that can only mean that they assume that whatever you say will likely be in their favor and not in that of your current client. That means you should try to stay out of this conflict as much as possible.

As long as there is no court which orders you to testify as a witness, there is no reason to get involved in this situation at all. When there is such a court order, you will have to testify under oath, so it will be hard to blame you for anything you say.

Answer (score 4):

You need to talk to your current company's lawyer.  Ignoring the issue can have serious consequences, and a lawyer can help you navigate them.  Since this is in the best interest of your employer, it's likely they'll want to be involved.

### IANAL

Be honest, take good notes, and remember that anonymous advice from strangers on the Internet (who don't even claim to be lawyers) should never substitute for professional legal assistance.

Comment: Best advice - Talk to your company's lawyer.  Keep them informed.  Do not do ANYTHING asked of you unless it comes on a letter signed by a judge (not the former company's lawyer).  Do not mention anything about this to your company's client.  If you feel "Squeezed," go see your own lawyer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not get afraid. It happens most of the time but I do not think that you should provide information and try to be witness. Let them do it. If you had softer relations with former company then It's totally up to you. If you think they can be helpful in your future career path, you should definitely help them or do not get stuck with that.

Answer (score -2):

A friend of mine was stuck in a situation like that. From the looks of it, the 'former company' in that case was exploiting their clients, and had a propensity to sue, or at least get lawyers involved, whenever the clients lost patience and bailed out. If it's your opinion that the 'former company' was jerking around their customers, assume they're jerking you around too. Best thing to do is say nothing.  Even what appears to you to be innocuous remarks can be used to pry open troublesome paths of inquiry.